# Is this error the reason my code always returns "no location"?

Tags: java, android, location

I am making an app that will require the user's location.  This is its code so far:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

LocationManager locationManager;
String provider;
Location location;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;


    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);


}

public void locationStuff(View view) {
    if (location != null) {

        Log.i("Location Info", "Location achieved!");

    } else {

        Log.i("Location Info", "No location :(");

    }

}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);

}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();


    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Double lat = location.getLatitude();
    Double lng = location.getLongitude();

    Log.i("Location info: Lat", lat.toString());
    Log.i("Location info: Lng", lng.toString());

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}


public void getLocation(View view) {

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    onLocationChanged(location);


}

}
```

It only returns " no location".  I am trying to get it to output "location achieved".  I attached a link to a picture of the error.  Please let me know if you see what is wrong.[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9fak.png)

Comment: Is "locationStuff()" something like "onClick()"?

Comment: yes, that is my onClick() method

Answer (score 0):

You can use GoggleLocationClient for better results.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    createLocationRequest();
    TextView mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mTextView);
    mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buildGoogleApipClient();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();


        }
    });

}
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApipClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Yes calling", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if(mLastLocation!=null){
        Toast.makeText(this,mLastLocation.getLatitude()+"-----"+mLastLocation.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    if (true) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }


}
protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    /*LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);*/
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    location = location;
    //mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    updateUI();
}

private void updateUI() {
    Toast.makeText(this,mLastLocation.getLatitude()+"-----"+mLastLocation.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
  }
```

Comment: I tried the code and the toast pops up.  Is there anything else I have to do? And if not how do i test that the location has been gotten?

Comment: Load your map and on MapReady function call you will get the location and movie your camera into location.